# plus/minus operator for python ±

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sympy

I am looking for a way to do a plus/minus operation in python 2 or 3. I do not know the command or operator, and I cannot find a command or operator to do this.

Am I missing something?

Comment: um, what is a plus/minus operation? Remember: In math, a function maps a value (or a set of values) from its definition to exactly one value...

Comment: I think you may want sympy for this.

Comment: @MarcusMüller he means as in when you do a square root, it has a negative and positive value simultaneously.

Comment: I think the only way for this is `if` blocks.

Comment: @tox123 exactly that is not the case. When you do a square root, you get exactly one value. That is the definition of the function "square root". What you want to say is "a problem of the form x² = Q has two solutions in the rational numbers if Q>0".

Comment: @tox123: I think you're right about needing sympy. I just found this [plus-minus object issue](https://code.google.com/p/sympy/issues/detail?id=2206)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Another possibility: [uncertainties](http://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/) is a module for doing calculations with error tolerances, ie

```
(2.1 +/- 0.05) + (0.6 +/- 0.05)    # => (2.7 +/- 0.1)
```

which would be written as

```
from uncertainties import ufloat

ufloat(2.1, 0.05) + ufloat(0.6, 0.05)
```

**Edit:** I was getting some odd results, and after a bit more playing with this I figured out why: the specified error is not a tolerance (hard additive limits as in engineering blueprints) but a standard-deviation value - which is why the above calculation results in

```
ufloat(2.7, 0.07071)    # not 0.1 as I expected!
```

Comment: This is not OP asking I think, the output should be `2.1+0.05=2.15/ 2.1-0.5=2.05 and 0.55/0.65` how you get that results?

Comment: This is binary +/- but the OP is looking for unary +/-. But thanks for this neat recommendation anyway.

Comment: ` the specified error is not a tolerance but a standard-deviation value` ... that would be fine, but... their documentation page shows tolerances. Bad documentation? https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/

Answer (score 55):

If you are looking to print the ± symbol, just use:

```
print(u"\u00B1")
```

Comment: The question is asking how to perform arithmetics using the +/- logic, not how to print the symbol.

Comment: Still a helpful answer for people who are looking for how to print the pm symbol :)

Answer (score 10):

Instead of computing expressions like

```py
s1 = sqrt((125 + 10 * sqrt(19)) / 366)
s2 = sqrt((125 - 10 * sqrt(19)) / 366)
```

you could use

```py
import numpy as np

pm = np.array([+1, -1])
s1, s2 = sqrt((125 + pm * 10 * sqrt(19)) / 366)
```

Comment: Nice! I posted [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63660407/4518341) based on this, that uses a generator expression instead of NumPy.

Answer (score 8):

If you happen to be using matplotlib, you can print mathematical expressions similar as one would with Latex. For the +/- symbol, you would use:

```
print( r"value $\pm$ error" )
```

Where the r converts the string to a raw format and the $-signs are around the part of the string that is a mathematical equation. Any words that are in this part will be in a different font and will have no whitespace between them unless explicitly noted with the correct code. This can be found on the relavent page of the [matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.0/users/mathtext.html).

Sorry if this is too niche, but I stumbeled across this question trying to find this very answer.

Comment: If you are only trying to print the value, I can use the keyboard shortcut `shift + alt` and the keyboard key with both `+` and `=` on it to produce `±` using a mac laptop.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want that for an equation like this;

[image]

Well there is no operator for that unless you don't use [**SymPy**](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), only you can do is make an `if` statement and find each multiplier.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such object in SymPy yet (as you saw, there is an issue suggesting one https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/5305). It's not hard to emulate, though. Just create a Symbol, and swap it out with +1 and -1 separately at the end. Like

```
pm = Symbol(u'±') # The u is not needed in Python 3. I used ± just for pretty printing purposes. It has no special meaning.
expr = 1 + pm*x # Or whatever
# Do some stuff
exprpos = expr.subs(pm, 1)
exprneg = expr.subs(pm, -1)
```

You could also just keep track of two equations from the start.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of computing expressions like

```
s1 = sqrt((125.0 + 10.0*sqrt(19)) / 366.0)
s2 = sqrt((125.0 - 10.0*sqrt(19)) / 366.0)
```

you could use

```
r = 10.0*sqrt(19)
s1, s2 = (sqrt((125.0 + i) / 366.0) for i in (r, -r))
```

*<sub>This is based on [Nico](https://stackoverflow.com/users/353337/nico-schl%C3%B6mer)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45684484/4518341), but using a generator expression instead of NumPy</sub>*

Answer (score 0):

A plus/minus tolerance test can be done using a difference and absolute against the tolerance you wish to test for. Something like:

```
tst_data = Number you wish to test
norm = Target number
tolerance = Whatever the allowed tolerance is.

if abs(tst_data - norm) <= tolerance:
do stuff
```

Using the `abs` function allows the test to return a +/- within tolerance as `True`