# How to write (+/-) in Python?

Tags: python, math, algebra

I'm new to Python and I have below this formula and I faced (+/-) before the square root. How could I write it in Python?

[image: Factorization Formula]

Comment: out of the box, you can't. Computer languages and mathematical equations don't always one-to-one. There are two "values/answers" packed in 1 expression here.

Comment: This equation is meant to calculate two solutions, you need to find the first using + and the second using -

Comment: With array you can

Comment: Are you asking what ± means (not a programming question) or how to write corresponding code in Python (in which case, where exactly are you stuck? what have you tried?)?

Comment: Do you want to print it or evaluate it?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/q/27872250/8966274

Comment: @melpomene I stuck in how to write this (±) in Python?

Comment: @bereal I need to program it in Python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way or another, you'll have to build two expressions, one with the plus sign and the other with the minus sign. This is the most straightforward way:

```
from math import sqrt

x1 = (-b + sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)) / 2.0
x2 = (-b - sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)) / 2.0
```

Of course you should calculate the value of `b*b - 4*a*c` only once and store it in a variable, and check if it's negative before proceeding (to avoid an error when trying to take the square root of a negative number), but those details are left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Why not with list ?

Comment: @deoncagadoes what do you mean?

Comment: x[0] = formula; x[1] = formula2;

Comment: That doesn't mean you have to write the same expression twice. You could e.g. `[-b + sign * sqrt(b*b - 4*a*c)) / 2 for sign in [1, -1]]`.

Comment: @melpomene How to print the results to your expression?

Comment: @melpomene and more importantly, how do you check if the result is an imaginary number?

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I don't understand the question. How do you check it with your code?

Comment: @melpomene See the comment at the end of my answer. We only need an extra variable, and with that you can check it easily.

Comment: OK ...? Then what are you asking from me?

Comment: @melpomene I'm not asking you. It's just that your proposed solution makes it hard to do the check.

Comment: `D = b*b - 4*a*c; if D < 0: error; [-b + sign * sqrt(D) / 2 for sign in [1, -1]]`

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially two formulas represented in one. There is no way to do that in Python. Just use two separate formulas. One with plus one with minus.