# Passing arguments self into function

Tags: python, oop

How can I pass in arguments (`a`, `b`, `c`) to a function for a quadratic formula without having to redefine them in the function? I know I could use `self.a` instead of just `a` inside the formula (same thing for `b` and `c`) but how do I pass in the argument `self.a` as `a`, `self.b` as `b`, and `self.c` into the function?

```
class Calc:

    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
    
    def quadraticformula(self):
        c = self.c
        b = self.b 
        a = self.a
        
        neg = ((b*-1)-(sqrt((b**2)-4*a*c)))/(2*a)
        pos = ((b*-1)+(sqrt((b**2)-(4*a*c))))/(2*a)
        return (pos,neg)
```

Comment: What's the point of that being a class at all? If you move the parameters from `__init__` to `quadraticformula`, then there's no instance state at all.

Comment: Rather use `def quadraticformula(self, a,b,c):`

Comment: @Sociopath But then the class would be pointless

Comment: You don't need to pass them into the function. You pass them when you create the `Calc` object. `c = Calc(1, 2, 3)` then `c.quadraticformula()`

Comment: BTW this got me thinking about how to do plus/minus more easily, and I ended up posting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63660407/4518341). In this case you could do `s = sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c); pos, neg = ((-b+i) / (2*a) for i in (s, -s))`.

Comment: Also BTW, welcome to SO! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want advice.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a class with a constructor function just use a normal function in general

```
def calc(a, b, c):
    neg = ((b*-1)-(sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)))/(2*a)
    pos = ((b*-1)+(sqrt(b**2 - 4*a*c)))/(2*a)
    return pos, neg
```

Then call the function:

```
>>> calc(1, 2, -3)
(1.0, -3.0)
```

Comment: like [Jack Diederich said](https://youtu.be/o9pEzgHorH0?t=180), *'The signature of "this shouldn't be a class" is that it has two methods, one of which is `__init__`.'*

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to redefine anything. The `__init__` method allows for all other methods of the class to be able to access that variable. So once you actually define a variable you passed to the **class** (you referenced it as a function, which its not) in the `__init__` method all you have to do it just reference it with whatever operation you need.

```
# within you quadraticformula method
...
neg = ((self.b*-1)-(sqrt(self.b**2 - 4*self.a*self.c)))/(2*self.a)
pos = ((self.b*-1)+(sqrt(self.b**2 - 4*self.a*self.c)))/(2*self.a)
return pos, neg
```

When passing attributes to the class you have create an instance of it like so:

```
a = # something
b = # something
c = # something

cl = Calc(a, b, c)
cl.quadraticformula() # call the method (a function with a method) of the function here

# You can call this method in the __init__ method if you want to 
# execute as soon as you call the class instead of using the instance 
# to reference it
class Calc:
  def __init__(self,a,b,c):
     self.a = a
     self.b = b
     self.c = c
     self.quadraticformula
```