# How to get both the values of fractional power or sqrt function in python?

Tags: python-3.x, math, module

For example
square root of 25 is +5 and -5.
But in python we get only the positive values.

```
import math
x=math.sqrt(25)
y=16**0.25
print(x,y)
```

We get output as 5,2 not -5,-2. How to get both the values?

Comment: It's trivial to do this yourself for square roots.

Answer (score 0):

**Unfortunately!**, python still has no direct operation to get both `plus/minus`

If you really need to get both values then you can use [uncertainties](https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/). The uncertainties package is a free, cross-platform program that transparently handles calculations with numbers with uncertainties (like 3.14±0.01). It can also yield the derivatives of any expression.

First, you need to install `uncertainties`. If you use `pip`, then

```
pip install --upgrade uncertainties
```

After that import modules in your file and do your operation.

```
import math
from uncertainties import ufloat
from uncertainties.umath import *
y=16**.25
print(x*math.sqrt(25), x*y)

# Output
# 5+/-5 2.0+/-2.0
```

Also, You have more quest then go through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27872250/plus-minus-operator-for-python-%C2%B1).